# Adding Google Play-services dependency causes "Error retrieving parent for item"

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-support-library

I keep running into errors when launching my app in an emulator:

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches 
the given name 
'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches 
the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches 
the given name 
'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches 
the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

I am using API 23, I have seen similar posts about the SDK version needs to match the support library.

However, all I have done is create the project and then add the Google-play services dependency and just try to run my app and i get these errors.

Below is my build.grade file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jamiefuller.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compile with api 23 since you are using compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'` (it has a dependency with support libraries).

Use:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```